# Where is the optimal point to “hide” in a shape?

Tags: geometry, optimization, puzzle

A puzzle I’ve wondered about but never got around to solving/verifying:

In the game Pokemon Let’s Go, the Pokemon Abra instantly teleports away if the player is detected within its line of sight.

Let’s say you’re in a square of length $s$ and one Abra randomly spawns in the square, with a random orientation, and has a 60-degree line of sight in front of it. **What’s the optimal place in the square to be so that Abra doesn’t teleport away?**

- If Abra has an unlimited length of sight (i.e. can see as far as possible within the square), it seems like any place in the square is equally good? Since given any place you choose to be, no matter where Abra spawns in the square, there is a uniform 5/6 chance that Abra doesn’t detect you due to its orientation?
- However, if Abra does have a limited length of sight (i.e. can only spot you from a distance $d$ away), my initial intuition would be to hide in the corner. But is there an elegant argument here without e.g. using calculus? And are there any convex polygons where hiding in a corner wouldn’t be the optimal place (if the intuition is correct)?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand for those unfamiliar with the context. What exactly is an "Abra"? Is it a single point? Is it an extended object? Is it a point with a vector attached to it (so that the phrasing "60 degree line of sight" makes sense)?

Comment: Right, exactly as you specified, Abra can be treated as a point with an orientation vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abra must first be within range of you, i.e. in the disc $D$ of radius $d$ around *you*. If within range, there is *always* a $\frac16$ chance its sight sector includes you, i.e. it spots you and Teleports – this is because circles and intersections of convex shapes are all convex. The two events are independent.

By minimising the intersection area of $D$ and the park (square) $P$, you therefore mimimise the chance of Abra spotting you. If $d\ge\sqrt2s$ there is no advantage to hiding in a corner, since $P\subseteq D$ no matter where $D$'s centre is within $P$. Otherwise – and this is *obvious*, not just intuition – placing $D$'s centre at a corner minimises the probability in question.

This argument naturally generalises to $P$ any convex shape, and indeed any shape if we assume there are no walls around the park.

Comment: Doh, much easier to think about it the other way around (area around you vs. area around Abra). Thanks!